# ion-datetime issue when 2 conditional values

Tags: angular, datetime, ionic-framework, ionic7

I have a simple ion-datetime on my stackblitz and I'm trying to add a default value and min hour available.

If I only have the default value in my condition: it's working well, If I only have the min hour value in my condition: it's working well, but if I have both properties together it doesn't work.

Here is my stackblitz sample : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cy669q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample.component.html

How can I keep both properties on the ion-datetime element ?

Thanks for your help

EDIT:

I have try to change the encode of time but have the same results

```
    if (this.page === 'destination') { //TIME DESTINATION
  const storedDate = format(new Date(this.form.get('date').value), 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm');
  let maxDeliveryDate: any;
  this.transportService.deliveries.forEach(delivery => {
    const originStartDate = format(new Date(delivery.origin.slots[0].start), 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm');
    if (!maxDeliveryDate || originStartDate > maxDeliveryDate) {
      maxDeliveryDate = originStartDate;
      const isSameday: boolean = format(new Date(storedDate), 'yyyy-MM-dd') === format(new Date(maxDeliveryDate), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
      //last date
      if(isSameday){
        //THIS PART BUG
        this.minVal = maxDeliveryDate;
        console.log('this.minVal: ', this.minVal); //2023-09-20T20:00
      } else {
        this.minVal = format(new Date(2000, 0, 1), 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm')
      }

    }
  })
} else { //TIME ORIGIN
  if(format(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') === this.form.get('date').value){
    this.minVal = format(addHours(new Date(), 1), 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm');
  } else {
    this.minVal = format(new Date(2000, 0, 1), 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm');
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a valid ISO 8601 datetime string to `value` property.

For example:

```
<ion-datetime
  presentation="time"
  min="2023-09-05T12:00"
  value="2023-09-05T14:59"></ion-datetime>
```

Here is an [example of a working app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cy669q-o4nrqb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample.component.html) with default and min values.

Comment: Thanks for your interest i have change my date time like you. But have the same results.
I have edited my post with more details.
Have you any more ideas?